# Ubuntu not saving vi directory, get error e502: is a directory

Tags: vi

Using Ubuntu, Linux

after executing --  `mkdir directname`

then --  `vi directname`

then write in what I need to inside it,
It will not save --  `:wq` or `:x`

but only --  `:q!`

which does not save what I have tried to create.

I get the error message --
`e502: "directname"  is a directory`.

There is no directory by that name yet. So how can I save my edits, and what am I doing wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: You do know that `mkdir` means create directory, yes?

Comment: Or just add the pathname first then the file name. `mkdir directname` then `vi directname/file.txt`

Comment: You are incorrect, there is a directory by that name, you just created it using `mkdir` in the step prior to the `vi`  command. What you have described is expected behaviour. As I'm not exactly sure what you want, my solution is;  Skip `mkdir` and go straight for `vi myfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might want to do is

```
mkdir directname
cd directname
vi mynewfile
```

`mkdir` stands for `make directory`, so you are creating and then opening a directory in vi, which lists contents from that directory (which is most probably empty since you have just created it). Does your editor window look like this:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v170)
"   /home/someusername/directname
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
./
```

Additionally I assume `vi` is just an alias for `vim` or `neovim`. I haven't seen a true `vi` for ages.